# Uniformly convergent sequence of functions $f_{k}$ Arzelà–Ascoli

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Prove the existence of an uniformly convergent subsequence $ \{ f_{k_{j}} \}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} $ of the sequence $ \{ f_{k} \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ in the following cases  :

a) Each  $f_{k} : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial with degree $ < $ 101 and coefficients $a_{0,k} , a_{1,k} , \ldots a_{100,k}$ with $[a_{j,k}] \leq 1$

b) Each $f_{k} : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ implies $f_{k}(0) = 0$, and is the antiderivative of a continuous function $g_{k}$ with $||g_{k}||_{C^{0}} \leq 1$

Do I have to think of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem to solve this ? What is the best approach ?

Comment: Yes, that's right! Have you looked at the statement of Arzlea-Ascoli? It says that you need to show that these sequences are bounded and equicontinuous. Why not try that? :)

Comment: P.S. I think part (b) is easier and more fundamental. Part (a) is very nearly a special case of part (b). I personally find the mean value theorem quite useful for checking equicontinuity...